# Need help on looping my code so it repeats instead of searching once

Tags: python, loops

i dont under stand how to make this loop

```
term = input("")
file = open('file.txt')
for line in file:
    line.strip().split('/n')
    if term in line:
        print(line)
    if term in line:
        print('Not on database, (try using caps)')
file.close()
```

(i know it is incorrect)

Comment: please provide a better description of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If by "repeat" you mean you want the user to be able to input a term multiple times, then just use a `while` loop.

```
while True:
    term = input("")
    file = open('file.txt')
    for line in file:
        line.strip().split('/n')
        if term in line:
            print(line)
        if term in line:
            print('Not on database, (try using caps)')
    file.close()
```

I am not sure how many times you want to be able to loop, but this loop will go indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is this.

```
term = input("")
# file is a python object by default, so it's better not to use it.
f = open('file.txt')
# Put each line in the file into a list
content = f.readlines()
for line in content:
    # str.strip() does not replace the original string
    # I modify it so that it is replaced.
    line = line.strip()
    if term in line:
        print(line)
    # The line below is unnecessary because it's the same condition as the previous if statement
    # if term in line:
        print('Not on database, (try using caps)')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file using `with` and loop through the lines.

```
term = input("")
with open('file.text') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if term in line.strip():
            print(line)
            break #breaks for loop and exits
```